# Previous user input persists when DataTemplateSelector returns the same template multiple times

Tags: .net, maui

I have implemented a generic onboarding workflow using a `CarouselView` that uses a `DataTemplateSelector` to display each `item` according to its `Type`:

```
    internal class OnboardingDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate RadioButtonTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate CheckBoxTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DatePickerTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PickerTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate EntryTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate EditorTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var model = (OnboardingModel)item;

            switch (model.Type)
            {
                case OnboardingModelType.RadioButton:
                    return RadioButtonTemplate;
                case OnboardingModelType.CheckBox:
                    return CheckBoxTemplate;
                case OnboardingModelType.DatePicker:
                    return DatePickerTemplate;
                case OnboardingModelType.Picker:
                    return PickerTemplate;
                case OnboardingModelType.Entry:
                    return EntryTemplate;
                case OnboardingModelType.Editor:
                    return EditorTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The `CarouselView` in XAML:

```
        <CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                      Style="{StaticResource CarouselViewStyle}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OnboardingDataTemplateSelector}"
                      PositionChanged="CarouselView_PositionChanged" />
```

A sample `DataTemplate`:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EntryTemplate" x:DataType="m:OnboardingModel">
            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Question}" Style="{StaticResource QuestionStyle}" />
                <Entry Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

`OnboardingModel` is an object model serializable to json:

```
    public class OnboardingModel
    {
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public List<string> Options { get; set; }
        public OnboardingModelType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum OnboardingModelType
    {
        RadioButton = 0,
        CheckBox,
        DatePicker,
        Picker,
        Entry,
        Editor
    }
```

I can now implement a new onboarding page simply by adding a snippet to a json file:

```
[
  ...
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Question": "How much do you weight?",
    "Type": 4
  },
  ...
  {
    "Id": 10,
    "Question": "What did you study?",
    "Type": 4
  },
  {
    "Id": 11,
    "Question": "What's your occupation?",
    "Type": 4
  },
  ...
]
```

I am running into a problem where if the same `DataTemplate` is reused consecutively, a previous user input is persisted and displayed in the subsequent `item`. For example, in the json above, the input value for page 1 is displayed in the `Entry` for page 11. Oddly, page 10 shows an empty Entry on load as expected. I surmise that this happens because the same instance of `DataTemplate` is returned by `DataTemplateSelector`. To test this theory, I want to create a new instance of `DataTemplate` for each `item`, but that is explicitly [prohibited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-7.0) in the documentation:

```
DataTemplateSelector objects have the following limitations:

The DataTemplateSelector subclass must always return the same template for the same data if queried multiple times.
The DataTemplateSelector subclass must not return another DataTemplateSelector subclass.
The DataTemplateSelector subclass must not return new instances of a DataTemplate on each call. Instead, the same instance must be returned. Failure to do so will create a memory leak and will disable control virtualization.
```

This seems to only impact `Entry` and `Editor`, as other `Type` does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code,I created a demo, but it works properly on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

**OnboardingModel.cs**

```
public class OnboardingModel 
    {
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public List<string> Options { get; set; }= new List<string>();
        public OnboardingModelType Type { get; set; }
    }
```

**OnboardingModelType.cs**

```
public enum OnboardingModelType 
    {
        RadioButtonType = 0,
        CheckBoxType,
        DatePickerType,
        PickerType,
        EntryType,
        EditorType
    }
```

**OnboardingDataTemplateSelector.cs**

```
public class OnboardingDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector 
{
    public DataTemplate RadioButtonTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CheckBoxTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DatePickerTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate PickerTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EntryTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EditorTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var model = (OnboardingModel)item;

        switch (model.Type)
        {
            case OnboardingModelType.RadioButtonType:
                return RadioButtonTemplate;
            case OnboardingModelType.CheckBoxType:
                return CheckBoxTemplate;
            case OnboardingModelType.DatePickerType:
                return DatePickerTemplate;
            case OnboardingModelType.PickerType:
                return PickerTemplate;
            case OnboardingModelType.EntryType:
                return EntryTemplate;
            case OnboardingModelType.EditorType:
                return EditorTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**TestPage.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage 
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var Items = new List<OnboardingModel>
        {
            new OnboardingModel { Question="How much do you weight?" ,Type = OnboardingModelType.EntryType  },
            new OnboardingModel { Question="What did you study?" ,Type = OnboardingModelType.EntryType  },
            new OnboardingModel { Question="What's your occupation?" ,Type = OnboardingModelType.EntryType  },
        };

        mListView.ItemsSource = Items;
    }
}
```

**TestPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:Selector"
             x:Class="Selector.TestPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="mRadioButtonTemplate" x:DataType="selector:OnboardingModel" >
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Question}"  />
                        <RadioButton Content="test"  />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="mCheckBoxTemplate"  x:DataType="selector:OnboardingModel">
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Question}"  />
                        <CheckBox    />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="mEntryTemplate" x:DataType="selector:OnboardingModel">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Question}"  />
                        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Placeholder="entry template" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>

            <selector:OnboardingDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector" 
                                                     RadioButtonTemplate="{StaticResource mRadioButtonTemplate}"  
                                                     EntryTemplate="{StaticResource mEntryTemplate}" 
                                                     CheckBoxTemplate="{StaticResource mCheckBoxTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <Label Text="ListView with a DataTemplateSelector" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <ListView x:Name="mListView" HasUnevenRows="True"   Margin="0,20,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

There are two main differences between my code and yours.

1.Use `ListView`  instead of `CarouselView`

2.if you use `ListView`,rembember to add tag `ViewCell` inner of `DataTemplate` , for example:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="mEntryTemplate" x:DataType="selector:OnboardingModel">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Question}"  />
                        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Placeholder="entry template" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dsrisPmzwXM5npLUTB3im4hZdF8JRKf/view?usp=sharing) is a short clip of the app that shows the bug I encounter. Is it possible to create the same UX using ListView instead of CarouselView?

Comment: Yes, you can do this using `CarouselView`. If you use `CarouselView`, please remove the tag `ViewCell` of `DataTemplate `. I tried to replace `Listview` with `CarouselView` , it works properly on my side.